# How to print subscripts/superscripts on the screen in C++?

Tags: c++, printing

Is it possible to print subscripts/superscripts ?
for example like that :  x² 
what are functions allow to do that ?

Comment: That has little to do with C++ and everything to do with the console / terminal you are using.

Comment: What operating system? What environment? Web? Linux? Console? Windows?

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on the environment you're running in. For a GUI system (Windows, Mac, Qt, etc.) you would need to consult the API documentation. For a text mode system, the best you could do is use specific characters in your current encoding. For instance, unicode has certain [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) that are super- or sub-scripts of other characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a GUI, you can change the size and orientation of the font.

There are also [superscript and subscript characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) available in Unicode that could be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the appropriate Unicode symbol, to cout or wcout depending on locale:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        std::cout << "x\u00b2" << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
        std::locale::global(std::locale("de_DE.UTF8"));
        std::wcout << L"x\u00b2" << std::endl;
}
```