# How to print superscript 3 in C++

Tags: c++, superscript

I am looking for a way to print superscript `3`, I googled a lot and I found a way to print superscript `2`:

```cpp
const char expo_square = 253;

void main () {
    std::cout << expo_square;
    return;
}
```

After some more googling, I came across the `Alt Keycode` for superscript `3`, which is:

```
Alt + 0179
```

The problem with this is that while compiling the `C++` source file:

```cpp
const char expo_cube = 0179;

void main () {
    std::cout << expo_cube;
    return;
}
```

I get an error: 
`3d.cpp(18): error C2041: illegal digit '9' for base '8'` 
(don't mind the file name)

So I tried the next logical thing, since the `Alt Keycode` for superscript `2` is `253`, I tried `Alt Keycode 254`, but all I ended up getting was:

```
■
```

So I wanted to ask:
`How can I print superscript 3 in C++?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print subscripts/superscripts on a CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597813/how-to-print-subscripts-superscripts-on-a-cli)

Comment: Also note that `void main()` is **not valid** C++.

Comment: What character encoding are you using in your terminal? Or, what terminal are you using? That is, does it support unicode, probably UTF-8?

Comment: @hyde I am using the `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022` terminal for compiling the code, via the `cl` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode superscript 3, or **³** is `\u00b3` in utf-16 and `\xc2\xb3` in UTF-8.

Hence, this would work with `cout`, assuming your console is UTF8.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\xc2\xb3" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To set your console in UTF-8 mode, you can do it in a number of ways, each is OS dependent, if needed at all.  On Windows, you can run `chcp 65001` from the command prompt before invoking your code:

[image]

If you can barely make out ³ getting printed above, let's zoom in closer:

[image]

Alternatively, you can do this in code via a Windows API, [SetConsoleOutputCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp)

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
```

So this works as well from a Windows program without having to do any environment changes before running the program.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << "\xc2\xb3" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);` is actually much more useful than it seems, I can store the `pi` symbol in a string itself and print it without any issues, this made life a lot easier, thank you for your help, really appreciate it :D

Comment: _"assuming your console is UTF8"_ is very important here. Maybe it's good to add that C++ doesn't specifically support unicode: it's the platform that parses it. So on any platform that doesn't have a console that supports UTF-8, the code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefix the expression with a `0`, the compiler considers this value to be represented in the *octal radix*. Values in octal radix must be in the range of `[0,7]`. The value `9` in the `0179` expression is outside of the *octal radix* range.

Try the following solution to print superscript 3:

```cpp
std::cout << "x\u00b3" << std::endl;
```

The result: **x<sup>3</sup>**

---

###### References

- [How to print subscripts/superscripts on the screen in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2992080/15032688)

Comment: But if I were to use: `Alt + 179`, I get: `│`. However if I used: `Alt + 0179` on my keyboard, I get: `³`. This is what is really confusing me.

Comment: If you have a new question, just make another post.

Comment: @Giant427 that's a question for Super User Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the question- and answer scopes this function can be used to get superscripts for any power (may be useful to someone):

```
std::string supow(int pow)
{
    std::string r{}, t{};
    if (pow<0) { r="\u207b"; pow*=-1; } else r.clear();
    t=itoa(pow); //stringize the pow for easier access to digits
    for (auto c:t)
    {
        switch(c-48)
        {
            case 0: r+="\u2070"; break;
            case 1: r+="\u00b9"; break;
            case 2: r+="\u00b2"; break;
            case 3: r+="\u00b3"; break;
            case 4: r+="\u2074"; break;
            case 5: r+="\u2075"; break;
            case 6: r+="\u2076"; break;
            case 7: r+="\u2077"; break;
            case 8: r+="\u2078"; break;
            case 9: r+="\u2079"; break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```